# How to Increase Speed of Downloading an MP3

Tags: php, download, mp3

I'm using the following code to force download some mp3 files that are stored on my server.   This works fine but it takes over 1 minute to download 1 mp3 file, even for a file that is 2.5MB. Something seems wrong for it take that long.  Any ideas what I can do to make this download a lot faster?

```
$fullfilename=$_GET['file'];
$filename=basename($fullfilename);

header('Content-type: audio/mpeg');
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"{$filename}\""); 
header("Content-Length: " . filesize($filename));
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
ob_clean();
flush();
readfile($fullfilename);
exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the internet connection between the server and your browser. PHP cannot do anything about it.